# Pivot grand total in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

SQL server code is as follows:

```sql
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols  = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+ QUOTENAME(category) AS [category]
    FROM  #temp_table2
    ORDER BY [category] DESC
FOR XML Path(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT *
                FROM( SELECT a.category,
                             a.report_month,
                             a.amount,
                             SUM(a.amount) OVER( PARTITION BY a.report_month) AS subtotal
                        FROM #temp_table2 a) Src
               PIVOT( SUM(amount) FOR category IN(' + @cols + ') ) Piv
               ORDER BY report_month'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

And the result is:

| report_month | subtotal | order_level | - order_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202004 | 8580491.16 | 8741662.16 | -161171.00 |
| 202005 | 2884973.00 | 4091963.00 | -1206990.00 |

My desired result is:

| report_month | order_level | - order_level | subtotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202004 | 8741662.16 | -161171.00 | 8580491.16 |
| 202005 | 4091963.00 | -1206990.00 | 2884973.00 |

How can I move the grand total to the far right?

Comment: By defining the order of the columns in your `ORDER BY`. You have stated you want them ordered by `category DESC`, and of `N'subtotal'`, `N'order_level;`, and `N'- order_level'` the value `N'subtotal'` *is* the largest, and so is ordered first.

Comment: `category` only includes `N'order_level` and `N'- order_level'` while `N'subtotal'` is sum by partition in the query.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM` define your columns properly then.

Comment: Also, what version of SQL Server (for a potentially different optimization)?

Comment: @AaronBertrand it is the 2019 version of SQL Server

Comment: You should look at replacing that `FOR XML PATH` noise with [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).